# how to get previous selected value in a select list

Tags: ajax, jsp, jquery

I have a form in that we have a drop down list ( apple, gova, lemon .. ) each one has some counter like apple =5, gova=3, lemon=6. If i select apple at first then count of apple becomes apple=4, suppose i want to change my selection from drop down list lemon, now lemon should become 5 and apple=5. how to do that ?

```
code :
           <select>
           <option>apple </option>
            <option>gova </option>
            <option>lemon</option>
            ..
            ..
            </select>
```

note : these list of fruits im getting from a table called fruits of mysql.

```
    table schema : fruit_table

     apple  gova lemon ... etc
      5      3     6    .....
```

in advance,thanks for your comments and solutions that you have given.

Comment: post some code that shows atleast you tried to do something

Answer (score 0):

Decrement the value only when the user submits the form. Not when he changes his select option.

Change the fruit_table schema columns to: fruit_name , count. From your example, it seems column names are fruit names

Comment: sir, i here we have to show the available fruits as soon as you choose the it from the list, not like after we do submit. so give me some idea how to do it.. thanks